# Pause or stop ALL bgworkers vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a code to stop all backgroundworkers in form 1 ( or pause them )

the names of the bgworkers are all very different so not bg1 bg2 bg3  etc.

is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put them in a list:

```
var workers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();
```

and then loop through this list.

Comment: Great sollution! didn't think of this